# export thread dump from jvisualvm

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I made a `thread dump` in `jvisualvm`.
How to export it?

[image]

I can't find any `export` button.

Comment: Can you copy/paste?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I can. But I thought there is some out-box way.

Comment: Copy `^V` is a pretty standard way to export data from a program.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I see

Comment: from the command line you can do `jstack {pid} > file` to write it to a file.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ^A^C is for export and ^V for import. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal that is a better way of putting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an answer, I suggest you use `^A^C` to select all and copy, and `^V` to paste into your favour editor. (Thank you @SubOptimal)  If you use IntelliJ, it can analyse the stack trace and let you navigate it.

From the command line you can do

```
jstack {pid} > file
```

to write directly to a file.